# WMIC query construction differences in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, windows, alpine-linux

This `wmic` query (`NODE`, `USER`, `PASS` all desensitised)...

```
wmic /NODE:10.00.00.1 /LOCALE:MS_409 /PRIVILEGES:ENABLE /TRACE:OFF /INTERACTIVE:OFF /FAILFAST:OFF /USER:domain\my_user /PASSWORD:myPass! /OUTPUT:STDOUT /APPEND:STDOUT /AGGREGATE:ON class StdRegProv CALL EnumKey ^&H80000002,"Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates"
```

`^&H80000002` is the uint32 conversion of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

... runs flawlessly in a CMD prompt in Windows. I can also run it in the context of a node package from my local windows machine with success, I'm going to assume this is because the `wmic` call is made specifically to the local machine (windows) where it is handled effortlessly. Returning to me a result containing what I require...

> res.sNames [ 'BB731A3DD8F089A6D4E59AF9D706...' ]

I created a docker container running Alpine and node where I host an express application. I followed the instructions below to install WMIC on Linux...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/885407/installing-wmic-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts

This installed successfully.

Now when I run the exact same query from a bash prompt in Ubuntu either via my Node app or a direct command, I'm receiving this result:

> $ wmic.exe /NODE:10.00.00.1 /LOCALE:MS_409 /PRIVILEGES:ENABLE /TRACE:OFF /INTERACTIVE:OFF /FAILFAST:OFF /USER:domain\my_user /PASSWORD:myPass! /OUTPUT:STDOUT /APPEND:STDOUT /AGGREGATE:ON class StdRegProv CALL EnumKey ^&H80000002,"Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates"
>
> [1] 426
>
> bash: H80000002,Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates: No such file or directory
>
> $ ERROR: Description = Access is denied.

I can't for the life of me work out whether this is due to a string formatting error in Linux vs Windows or whether Linux is running a different variant of `wmic` that isn't resolving my query correctly?

After trying @A.B's suggestion I removed the caret/ampersand (^&) altogether and this was the output:

> $ wmic /NODE:10.23.0.11 /LOCALE:MS_409 /PRIVILEGES:ENABLE /TRACE:OFF
> /INTERACTIVE:OFF /FAILFAST:OFF /USER:aim4gain\svc_certdisc
> /PASSWORD:finiTAryduRationmagneticDialuP! /OUTPUT:STDOUT
> /APPEND:STDOUT /AGGREGATE:ON class StdRegProv CALL EnumKey
> H80000002,"Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates"
>
> ERROR:
>
> Description = Access is denied.

It's the same query with the same credentials I'm running from both operating systems - however I get no auth problems from Windows.

Comment: use quotes. the [1] 426 is a forked command because of the `&` somewhere. And there's no relation between Debian and Alpine Linux

Comment: @A.B Hi there, thanks for the correction and the suggestion - I'll give it a bash now!

Comment: @A.B Added a comment to the post

Comment: I didn't tell you to remove something which might be part of the parameters, I told you to escape them. YOu have to understand how it's working: https://manpages.debian.org/bash/bash.1#QUOTING (or https://manpages.debian.org/dash/dash.1#Quoting etc.) . note: I don't know anything about wmic

Comment: Understood. In command prompt since & is a special char, you must escape it with ^, resulting in ^&. And in bash, as you've pointed out you must escape the & with \. I did that and the result was the same outcome as the one I followed up with in my question. Thanks for your help anyway though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, after hours of testing this with very obscure error messages. Make sure you escape absolutely everything in bash style not in a windows fashion.

Note:

- `\$` instead of `^&`
- Wrap USER value in ''
- Wrap PASSWORD value in ''

References here (thanks to @A.B):

https://manpages.debian.org/buster/bash/bash.1.en.html#QUOTING

```
$ wmic /NODE:10.23.0.11 /LOCALE:MS_409 /PRIVILEGES:ENABLE /TRACE:OFF /INTERACTIVE:OFF /FAILFAST:OFF /USER:'domain\my_user' /PASSWORD:'myPass!' /OUTPUT:STDOUT /APPEND:STDOUT /AGGREGATE:ON class StdRegProv CALL EnumKey \&H80000002,"Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates"
Executing (StdRegProv)->EnumKey()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 0;
        sNames = {"BB731A3DD8F089A6D4E59AF9D70601F9CBB94A9D"};
};
```